# problems in using custom Hook

Tags: react-hooks

I am starting with react just learning to create Custom hooks,but having issue with while creating this custom hook to turn a sentence to sentence case.There is no error and also not showing the output(I want like "HeLLO WORld" to as "Hello world")Can't find out where I am making the mistake,kindly help me out.Here is the code

```
The custom hook-

    import UsePascalCase from "../CustomHooks/UsePascalCase"
    export default function TextBoxDemo(){
    var text="";
    function handleOnInputEntry(e){
       text=e.target.value
     }
     var pascal=UsePascalCase(text)
     return(
        <>
        <textarea onChange={handleOnInputEntry}></textarea>
        <span>{pascal}</span>
        </>
     )
    }
The input box,where want to use the hook
    export default function UsePascalCase(str){
        var firstCharacter=str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
        var restCharacters=str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        var sentence=firstCharacter+restCharacters
        return sentence
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `text` variable needs to be reactive to see changes in your application. More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
Try:

```
 import UsePascalCase from "../CustomHooks/UsePascalCase"
 import { useState } from "react"
    export default function TextBoxDemo(){
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    function handleOnInputEntry(e){
       setText(e.target.value)
     }
     var pascal=UsePascalCase(text)
     return(
        <>
        <textarea onChange={handleOnInputEntry}></textarea>
        <span>{pascal}</span>
        </>
     )
    }
```